# Proof regarding expected value on a Normal Distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, expected-value

I've been working on a list of normal distribution exercises that so far had been pretty straightforward, mostly with applications and consultations on tables. This last one has got me, so far.

*If $X$ is $N\left( {\mu ,{\sigma ^2}} \right)$ distributed, show that ${\rm E}\left( {\left| {X - \mu } \right|} \right) = \sigma \sqrt {{2 \over \pi }} $.*

My first idea was to go from the definition of expected value on a normal distribution: $${\rm E}\left( X \right) = {1 \over {\sigma \sqrt {2\pi } }}\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {x{e^{ - {{{{(x - \mu )}^2}} \over {2{\sigma ^2}}}}}dx} $$  and then trying to plug in the $|X - \mu |$ factor where originally there was only an $x$, but I have no clue if I'm allowed to do that.

Anyway, following this line of thought I ended up with a non-convergent integral:
  $$\eqalign{
  & {\rm E}[|X - \mu |] = {1 \over {\sigma \sqrt {2\pi } }}\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\left| {x - \mu } \right|{e^{ - {{{{(x - \mu )}^2}} \over {2{\sigma ^2}}}}}dx}   \cr 
  & t = {{x - \mu } \over {\sqrt 2 \sigma }},{\rm{ }}dt = {1 \over {\sqrt 2 \sigma }}dx  \cr 
  & {\rm E}[|X - \mu |] = {1 \over {\sqrt 2 \sigma \pi }}\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {2\sigma |t|{e^{{t^2}}}} \sqrt 2 \sigma dt  \cr 
  & {\rm E}[|X - \mu |] = {{2\sigma } \over {\sqrt \pi  }}\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {|t|{e^{{t^2}}}}  \cr} $$
  I'm not worried about getting a full answer, I'd love to get insight to try better approaches right now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{\Bbb R}|t|e^{-t^2}dt=\int_0^\infty 2te^{-t^2}dt=1.$$

Comment: Just saw I made a mistake regarding a 2 that's actually supposed to be a square root of 2 in the middle. Your final touch does it, I guess. Thanks.